# Switch databases dynamically with ease in php project using PDO

Tags: php, database, pdo, database-connection

I'm new to PDO and php. Trying to switch databases. A class is defined for PDO connection. when i am changing the database name to database2 manually in following code "private $sqlx = "use database1";". it is working fine. Now how i can change this database name dynamically with php in runtime.

```
class Database
    {
    private $sqlx = "use database1";
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost';
    private $user = "root";
    private $pass = "";
    public $conn;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        try{
            
            $this->conn = new PDO($this->dsn,$this->user,$this->pass);

            $this->conn->exec($this->sqlx);
        }   
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

i want to assign value in private $sqlx from $_SESSION["database"]
i want to work out this code  private $sqlx = $_SESSION["database"];
but i am getting error "Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in F:\xampp\htdocs........."

Comment: so you have two different classes for different databases right? and all of them uses mysql

Comment: class database is already defined. As you can watch a variable (private $sqlx = "use database1";) is defined in this class. where database1 is the name of database. Now when i am changing database1 to database2 by editing script. database2 come into use. I want to perform this through php (for example from select)

Comment: so you have single class and you are changing names manually, create a setter to set a private property for the class which will store db name

Comment: You could change the constructor to take the database name as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you want to connect to two different databases. In this case you should provide the name of the database (and maybe other dynamic parameters like user name and password) as a parameter to your DB connection class and make a new instance of that class for every database you want to connect to:

```
public function __construct(string $dbName)
{
    try{
        
        $this->conn = new PDO($this->dsn,$this->user,$this->pass);

        $this->conn->exec('use ' . $dbName);
    }   
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Note: the `string` type annotation assumes you are using PHP7+

You could also include the name in your dsn directly, so you don't need to call `exec` separately: `"mysql:dbname={$dbName};host=localhost"`

**Edit:** In addition to the comment below, if you really only want to have one instance (and therefore connection) you could also add another method:

```
public function changeDatabase(string $name) {
    $this->conn->exec('use ' . $name);
}
```

Comment: Hi jumper85 thanks for reply. how i can change the value stored in $dbName on runtime in above code. please elaborate with code.

Comment: you don't need to, because you are making two instances: `$db1 = new Database('database1'); $db2 = new Database('database2');`

Comment: I extended my answer above to fit your request (untested on my side).

Comment: Please understand my real situation. I am coding a php project for ten persons. For this i have ten databases with same structure. Now whenever i want i can switch to any of one database to read write by simply selecting from drop down menu or while logging and assigning values to $SESSION[]. In above code which i have provided when i am changing the database name in code stored in $sqlx  variable it works fine at runtime. now this action is to be performed through dopdown menu

Comment: that's ok, every time you make a request to the server, you can read your current name from `$_SESSION` and create the instance with your name like `new Database($_SESSION['dbName']);`. unfortunatelly classes that have PDO instances cannot be serialized inside the session, so that's the only way I see. may I ask, what you are using as frontend?

Comment: class Database
    {
    private $sqlx = "use database1";

Comment: that's the initial value, but after you created the connection, it doesn't matter, if you change `$sqlx` attribute or not, you have to change the database used by the connection, check `changeDatabase` from my answer above, if you want, you can also change the value of `$sqlx` in this method, if you have a getter in the database class.

Comment: class Database
    {
    private $sqlx = "use database1";. This is the code, so if i am changing code to private $sqlx = $some another variable;. now this $some another variable stores name of database. this $some another variable is already been initialized. now how to implement this change in code.

Comment: as mentioned in my comment before, check `changeDatabase` method of my anser, in there you can also set your private `$sqlx` attribute. but you always have to change the used database in the connection as well, because otherwise the database connection is not aware of the change.

Comment: i have tried changeDatabase before it is not changing database name. even tried assigning null, kill and unset before executing    $this->conn->exec('use ' . $name); but database is not changing in connection. but at the same time if i am editing the code with another database name in    private $sqlx = "use database1"; its working.

Comment: I have to ask again, what do you use as frontend? what happens, if you change the drop down?

Comment: I think at the moment using changeDatabase databases changes. but when i am working on any mysql call.  code  private $sqlx = "use database1";  in class Database. again starts using database1. so if it possible to replace $sqlx = "use database1"; code with $sqlx = $some variable;  this $some variable stores name of database. initially whatever database name is stored in this $some variable that will be loaded in connection. and if this $some variable is changed and now it contains other database name, automatically it will be loaded.

Comment: front end is web page based on html, jquery, ajax. When i am selecting value from dropdown. with the help of ajax i am able to change values of $sql with changeDatabase method as you suggested. but with another query again $sqlx gets initial value. If am assigning  null are empty string to $sql then PDO connection giving error.

Comment: so you make a request every time the drop down changes, and provide the value for the database name? if that is the case, then why not remove the `$sqlx` attribute completely and only use the name in the constructor of your database class? in your `index.php` or whatever file you have, you make a new instance with the correct name. if this is not working, than I think I'm missing some information on the issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to sort out the problem.
**Code for class:**

```
class Database
{
private $sqlx;
private $host = "localhost";
private $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost';
private $user = "root";
private $pass = "";
public $conn;

public function __construct($sqlx)
{
    $this->sqlx = $sqlx;
    try{
        $this->conn = new PDO($this->dsn,$this->user,$this->pass);
        $this->conn->exec($this->sqlx);
    }   
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

and i have to allocate an instance of class as follows

```
<?php
session_start();
$ttt=$_SESSION["db"];
require_once 'db.php';
$db = new Database($ttt);
```

here i am storing string "use databasename" in $_SESSION["db"] which i am able to manipulate anywhere.

Cheers!